# Why does Realm create only 8 fields in new RealmObject in some devices?

Tags: android, realm

I use realm-java ver:3.5 in Android studio.
I have a JAVA class named Message that extends RealmObject. It has 9 fields with their Getter and Setter.In some mobile devices when I run my app, it'll crash and this error appears in logs:

> Field count is less than expected - expected 9 but was 8

I found which field that didn't create, so I changed its name, type and order in class and reran the app but all results were same.

Finally, I added a new field else.Realm only created 8 fields again!!

WHY doesn't Realm create my RealmObject correctly?

```
public class Message extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long commandId;

    private Integer id;

    @Required
    private Long initTimeStamp;

    @Required
    private String messageText;

    private User sender;
    private User receiver;

    private MyDateTime sendDate;
    private MyDateTime readDate;

    @Required
    private Integer messageStatus = STATUS_NEW;

public Message() {
    }
/*
 * all setters and getters
 * ...

*/
}
```

Comment: are you doing schema migrations?

Comment: If I do a migration it will be correct. The problem happens when I uninstall app and install it again!

Comment: How do you reinstall app? Do you have instant run enabled?

Comment: No,instant run is off. Just now I replace .migration(new Migration()) with .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded() and the problem solved. I think old realm database did not remove from device correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added `android:allowBackup="true"` in manifest file in application section,by default it's true too.So I changed it to `android:allowBackup="false"` and `android:restoreAnyVersion="false"` , so my problem solved.

**MORE EXPLANATION**
When we grant `allowBackup` to our Application,in fact we say to android OS "Hey Android,If I uninstall this app, before that take a backup for it's **shared-preference**, **database** and other app data and put them away.
When we reinstall app, Android replace current data with the old one!